# Split a long table while generating pdf

Tags: apache, pdf, xslt, pdf-generation, apache-fop

To generate a pdf document with table i use Apache POF software. I have a collection of some objects i want to represent as table. Each cell of this table contains a couple of fields. And three of four cells compose a row. The issue i have is that i shouldn't split cells in a row between two pages (for example the situation when the 1st half of the cell is printed on the one page and the rest of this cell will b printed on another page is not allowed). I was trying to resolve this issue w/ **"keep-with-next="always""** attribute in **"fo:table-row"** but it didn't help. Any ideas would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `keep-together.within-page="always"` on the `fo:table-row` elements: this prevents page breaks to happen inside the content of a row.

Using `keep-with-next="always"` does not achieve what you want because if forbids page breaks between the *end* of a row and the *beginning* of the next one, while leaving mid-row breaks allowed.

Comment: Thank you! Now everything is fine.